# What does it mean to protect / unprotect a cookie?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, tor-button

In the Tor button menu, there is a "Cookie Protections" item, which opens up a dialog that lists all my cookies, and allows me to protect or unprotect each (and specify whether new cookies should be protected or unprotected by default).

What does protecting or unprotecting a cookie do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That entire thing currently doesn't work, due to a Firefox bug. More details can be found in Tor's bug tracker. I would recommend you ignore the thing for now until it works :(

edit:
It's supposed to help keep cookies across getting a new identity, so you don't get logged out of websites for example.

Comment: What is it supposed to do, though?

Comment: updated my answer, hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks - keeping cookies across getting a new identity sounds like exactly what I want! One more question: what is the relevant Tor issue? The only one I could find that seemed related was https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/10353, but that doesn't match what I'm seeing - that describes the Cookie Protection dialog being empty, but I'm seeing cookies being listed there (they're just not kept across getting a new identity, in spite of me protecting them).